# post featured image php array size issue

Tags: php, arrays, size, thumbnails

I have just added the code `<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail (array(786,400));?>` to my post php file to have the post thumbnail shown on it, and I have used (array) in my code to specify my image size without referring to functions.php file .... BUT the thing is that the size of the shown image is (533 x 400) pixels !!

is there some kind of ratio that the (array) has to have or what can I do to have the same size that I have specified??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Note that `the_post_thumbnail (array(786,400));` will not try to distort the image, it will maintain the aspect ratio of the image. looks like in your case it has re-sized the image to 400 on one side and other side is reduced proportionately.

Comment: yea I think that's what happening, is there any way to show the image with a specific dimension ?

Comment: Try this link [http://ilfilosofo.com/blog/2010/03/11/plugin-creates-wordpress-thumbnails-on-demand/](http://ilfilosofo.com/blog/2010/03/11/plugin-creates-wordpress-thumbnails-on-demand/)